# gradle object in a gradle build script

Tags: groovy, gradle

Consider the following method invokation containing in the gradle build script:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady{taskGraph ->
                println gradle.toString()
                println "Ready"
}
```

It prints

```
build 'task_graph'
Ready
```

I thought we work in the scope of [Project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) object, since `gradle` should be a property of that `Project` object. But there is neither property nor even method with such name. Why can we use it in the build script?

Comment: Huh?  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:gradle

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think your confusion is that there exists a `getGradle()` method on the `Project` interface but no such public field named `gradle`. This is a Groovy feature. In Groovy, getter and setter methods can by referenced as properties. For example:

```
println project.description // same as project.getDescription()

project.description = 'My java project' // same as project.setDescription('My java project')
```

I'd highly suggest familiarizing yourself with Groovy by checking out [their documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Getting+Started+Guide). You'll see a lot of differing syntax in Gradle examples simply because there are many different ways to accomplish the same thing in Groovy.